# Merge Multisearch into a single query in Elasticsearch and execute over all of the indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a `python` application that constructs `4` very complex (but identical in terms of schema) `elasticsearch` queries using `elasticsearch-dsl`. Each one of them is executing to a separate index. My goal is to merge them together with all of their fields (e.g. if there is a key `samples` list in all of them, I need `samples` of all of them to be united into the final `list` of the final query) and *execute over all of the indices*. I am not sure what is best here, and if its possible to do with `elasticsearch-dsl` at all. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understood your requirements, but at least for executing one query over multiple indices, you should check out [Search multiple data streams and indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multiple-indices.html#search-multiple-indices).

So you could use

```
GET /my-index-1,my-index-2,my-index-whatever/_search
```

And in this case, if all your indices have the same prefix, you could even use:

```
GET /my-index-*/_search
```

Comment: It is part of it, another part is how could I combine the very long queries together without the need to reconstruct it manually myself. It might not be possible, but I still asked, maybe someone has an idea on that. Lets' say that there are `4` queries: `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, how to merge them directing to all of the indices? Queries can be built up to very large ones using `elasticsearch-dsl`.

Comment: Can you maybe provide an example of those queries? Otherwise - at least for me - it's hard to guess what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multisearch api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search) using which you can combine multiple queries and even target to multiple indices.

e.g.

```
GET index1,index2,index3/_msearch
{ }
{"query":{//q1}}
{ }
{"query":{//q2}}
{ }
{"query":{//q3}}
{ }
{"query":{//q4}}
```

You can even limit the indices for a particular query. E.g. if you want `q4` to execute on only `index1` then change as below:

```
GET index1,index2,index3/_msearch
{ }
{"query":{//q1}}
{ }
{"query":{//q2}}
{ }
{"query":{//q3}}
{"index":"index1"}
{"query":{//q4}}
```

In this case `q1`, `q2` and `q3` will be executed on indices `index1`, `index2` and `index3` whereas `q4` will execute only on `index1`.